# terraform apply in Azure Devops pipeline not destroying resources

Tags: azure, terraform, databricks, azure-databricks

I have an azure devops pipeline to build resources using terraform. I'm using the terraform extension for Azure Devops. The pipeline works fine and is able to build resources using terraform init, plan and apply stpes but when I remove resources from code, the command doesn't destroy the resource. It somehow doesn't seem to even identify that there is a resource to be deleted. Any reason why this would happen? I am running the pipeline in the self hosted agent. I was outputting the plan to a x.tfplan and applying the x.tfplan. I removed it in case the plan was being cached but the issue persists. Below is the stripped version of the cicd file. I can confirm that                 - `checkout: self` step ensures that the latest version of code is being checked out (I also confirmed by checking the contents of directory in command line).

```
name: $(Build.BuildId).$(date:yyyyMMdd)

parameters:
  - name: environment
    displayName: "environment"
    type: string
    default: dev
    values:
      - dev
      - test

trigger:
  - main
pr: none

variables:
  - group: "VG-SHARED"
  - group: "VG-${{parameters.environment}}"


pool:
  # vmImage: "windows-2019"
  name: "SWC Self Hosted Windows 01"

stages:
  - stage: "Deploy_Databricks_Resources"
    displayName: "Deploy Databricks resources in ${{ parameters.environment }}"
    jobs:
      - deployment: "Deploy_Databricks_Resources"
        displayName: "Deploy Databricks resources in ${{ parameters.environment }}"
        environment: ${{ parameters.environment }}
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - checkout: self
                - task: TerraformInstaller@1
                  displayName: "tf install"
                  inputs:
                    terraformVersion: "1.4.0"
                - task: TerraformTaskV4@4
                  displayName: "tf init"
                  inputs:
                    provider: "azurerm"
                    command: "init"
                    # commandOptions: '-reconfigure'
                    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\${{ parameters.environment }}'
                    backendServiceArm: "XX"
                    backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: "XX"
                    backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: "XXX" #"$(storageName)"
                    backendAzureRmContainerName: "tfstate"
                    backendAzureRmKey: "${{ parameters.environment }}-terraform.tfstate"
                - task: TerraformTaskV4@4
                  displayName: "tf plan"
                  inputs:
                    provider: "azurerm"
                    command: "plan"
                    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\${{ parameters.environment }}'
                    commandOptions: "-var-file terraform.tfvars"
                    environmentServiceNameAzureRM: '$(azdoResourceConnection)'
                - task: TerraformTaskV4@4
                  displayName: "tf apply"
                  inputs:
                    provider: "azurerm"
                    command: "apply"
                    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\${{ parameters.environment }}'
                    commandOptions: ""
                    environmentServiceNameAzureRM: '$(azdoResourceConnection)'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the working directory and can run these commands

```py
    cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
    terraform state list
```

If 0 resources are displayed then the state file is being deleted after you run terraform apply stage.